# Uncaught TypeError - issue mapping over json object in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component which is pulling in user data, and should be able to display one of the values from the JSON object. However, I'm getting the following `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.reasons.map is not a function` error. I believe its because it is expecting an array vs an object, but not quite sure how to check or convert as needed. It should be able to map over the object and render the value of `subscription.current_period_end`

This is the JSON object:

```
{
  "displayName": "username",
  "email": "user@email.com",
  "entitled": true,
  "id": "23456789",
  "subscription": {
    "canceled_at": 1508519952,
    "current_period_end": 1524765490,
    "is_premium": true,
    "is_renewing": false,
    "plan_type": "Annual",
    "saved": true,
    "status": "Active"
  },
  "country": "us",
  "language": "en"
}
```

**React Component**

```
class CancelConfirm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      reasons: []
    }
    this.processData = this.processData.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchContent(this.processData)
  }


  fetchContent(cb) {
    superagent
      .get('/api/user')
      .then(cb)
  }


  processData(data) {
    this.setState({
      reasons: data.body
    })
  }

  render(props) {
    const content = this.props.config.contentStrings
    const reason = this.state.reasons.map((reason, i) => {
      return ( 
        <p key={i}>{reason.subscription.current_period_end}</p>
        )
    })
    console.log(reason)

    return ( 
    <div className = 'confirm' >
      <p className = 'confirm-subpara' >{reason}</p> 
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CancelConfirm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `this.state.reasons` is response object from JSON, object doesn't have map function it's only for iterator values such as `new Array()` if you are trying to show reason you would simply do

Currently I don't know why you are trying to iterate over object when it has no array array data, maybe I got your question wrong so please specify why you even did `map` instead of simple object reference.

```js
var API_RESPONSE = {
  "body": {
    "displayName": "username",
    "email": "user@email.com",
    "entitled": true,
    "id": "23456789",
    "subscription": {
      "canceled_at": 1508519952,
      "current_period_end": 1524765490,
      "is_premium": true,
      "is_renewing": false,
      "plan_type": "Annual",
      "saved": true,
      "status": "Active"
    },
    "country": "us",
    "language": "en"
  }
}

class CancelConfirm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
      reasons: false
    }
    
    this.processData = this.processData.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchContent(this.processData)
  }


  fetchContent(cb) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      cb(API_RESPONSE)
    }, 2000)

  }


  processData(data) {
    this.setState({
      reasons: data.body
    })
  }

  render(props) {
    if (!this.state.reasons) return (<i>Loading ....</i>)

    const reason = <p>{this.state.reasons.subscription.current_period_end}</p>

    return ( 
    <div className = 'confirm' >
      <p className = 'confirm-subpara' >{reason}</p> 
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CancelConfirm />, document.getElementById('react'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: This is erroring out with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current_period_end' of undefined`

Comment: can you please share full JSON response? as probably you shared only a chunk not full response. Thanks

Comment: @Matt I've update my answer with running snippet, please let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can't `map()` over an `Object`. As such it would be better to do something like this:

```
render(props) {
  const content = this.props.config.contentStrings
  const { reasons } = this.state;
  const keys = Object.keys(reasons);

  return (
    keys.map((k, i) => {
      return <p key={i}>{reasons[k].subscription.current_period_end}</p>
    })
  )
}
```